# CSS and spacing

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem with this part of CSS (it doesn't seem to be a lot, but I don't understand ... )

```
#bas {
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-top:10%;
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
}

#haut {
    position:absolute;
    background:#FFFF00;
    margin-top:0%;
    width:100%;
    height:10%;
}
```

So, in my mind, #haut will take 10% of the page and #bas will take the other 90% with "haut" above "bas".

But if you look on this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/ypteL83a/2/
There are spaces between the top of the page and "haut", and a greater space between "haut" and "bas", and I was wondering why is this space here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"There are spaces between the top of the page"_ -> `body{margin: 0}`

Comment: @Vucko Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `top` for absolute positioning, not `margin-top`:

https://jsfiddle.net/ypteL83a/4/

```
body
{
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
  margin:0 ;
}

#bas {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #ccc;
  top:10%;
  width:100%;
  height:90%;
}

#haut {
  position:absolute;
  background:#FFFF00;
  top:0%;
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a default margin on your content, if you put margin:0; on your #bas div it will align with the top element.

```
#bas {
position:absolute;
background-color: #ccc;
margin-top:10%;
width:100%;
height:90%;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: But I put margin:0% on the body tag to remove border on all my picture :)

Comment: @RaphaelSchimchowitsch it's better my solution, with this solution the absolute positioning will stack in his place (correct) but it hides the top border. This answer is better if you have relative positioning, not absolute.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude i agree, didn't notice the top border dissapeared :)

Comment: I only try to say to you that margins with position absolute is not a good practice because in absolute elements them go out of the normal flow, so margins don't work exactly as you want. Good luck and thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In #bas **margin-top: 10%** will take up the top 10% of the height of the browser Window.

Answer (score 0):

When u use margin/padding top/bottom it's calculated based on width and not height. I am pretty sure that's the case here

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
 #bas {
            position:absolute;
            background-color: #ccc;
            margin:0 auto;
            width:100%;
            height:90%;
        }
```